# Traduciendo aplicaciones móviles

Tags: discusión, traducciones

En el caso de la [aplicación para Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow) se deberían revisar los textos para los distintos lenguajes que soporta la aplicación, por ejemplo en la descripción de la aplicación se puede notar este error gramatical :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de la [aplicación para iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808?mt=8), esta actualmente únicamente soporta lenguaje inglés, sería conveniente que con la creación de los nuevos sitios también se agreguen descripciones adecuadas para estos nuevos sitios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso ¿quien podría ayudar a realizar los cambios?

Comment: La aplicación es exclusiva para [so], no para otros sitios. Si bien la descripción aparece en español en Play Store, es sólo la descripción y no se va a localizar la interfaz. Entiendo que la corrección del texto debería solicitarse en [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app), porque no tiene nada que ver con SOes. Para otros sitios de SE está [Stack Exchange para Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin).

Comment: Me parece un excelente propuesta @Elenasys cualquier cosa a las ordenes